# Javascript: outside variable used inside closure

Tags: javascript, closures

I have a simple jquery popup plugin. The usage looks like this:

```
$("#popupContainer").popup({
    onOpen: function () { },
    onClose: function () { }
});
$("#popupContainer").popup("open", "/Home/PopupContent");
$("#popupContainer").popup("close");
```

This works good.

However, i want to pass a different onOpen callback for different url's i have. So i thought about making a wrapper over the plugin, like this:

```
var popupPlugin = {};
(function () {
    var onOpen = null;
    var onClose = null;

    $("#popupContainer").popup({
        onOpen: function () {
            if (onOpen) {
                onOpen();
            }
            onOpen = null;
        },
        onClose: function () {
            if (onClose) {
                onClose();
            }
            onClose = null;
        }
    });

    popupPlugin.open = function (url, callback) {
        onOpen = callback;
        $("#popupContainer").popup("open", url);
    }
    popupPlugin.close = function (callback) {
        onClose = callback;
        $("#popupContainer").popup("close");
    }
}());

// usage
popupPlugin.open("/Home/PopupContent", function () {
    // specific callback
});
```

This works as expected (i now have different callbacks), but i am worried that i am creating memory leaks somehow.

Is the implementation of the `popupPlugin` wrapper good?

Comment: This question would be better asked at http://s.tk/review

Comment: What is your definition of "good"?

Comment: @whymarrh: "Safe", "Efficient", "Not creating problems"

Comment: @thejh: because `var onOpen` is used inside a closure, wouldn't a copy of that variable be "remembered" each time i call the `popupPlugin.open' function?

Comment: @RaraituL: No, where should it be remembered? I mean, yes, the function is made to remember the `callback` in the `onOpen` variable, but it would as well overwrite previous storings - and you wipe the `onOpen` variable in the handler, just as you wanted it.